# PNG file looks completely different inside of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, textures

I purchased the "Set Builder: Back street Manhattan"  with came with some png textures such as [this one](http://pizzadog.org/posting/unity/Store.png).

When I open the file in the browser or any editing program, it looks completely transparent except for the windows.   When I drag the image into Unity, it is completely opaque bricks (which is what I want)  If I duplicate the image and drag that image into Unity, it is again completely opaque bricks.  If I save a copy of the image with photoshop or another application, the information that contained the bricks is lost and it is now mostly transparent, except it has some blotchy white textures which also aren't seen in the photoshop interpretation.  Every texture in this folder is doing this same behavior.  Are these files corrupted or compressed?  How do I retain the brick information into an image editing program besides taking a screenshot within Unity ? Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8AJi.png) : of dragging images onto cubes in Unity. Left is a Photoshop copy. Right is attached image

The developer has not replied to my direct questions.

Comment: did you find a solution, same problem here with bought asset xd

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in Photoshop.

Layer>layer mask>from transparency. Then right click on the layer to disable the transparency.

Answer (score 1):

it can be your texture `import format` [image]

try changing its format to `true color`

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond.  This seems to be a misleading problem to explain.  Unity is importing the PNG in the way that I want. I have made work with this PNG inside of Unity.  My problem lies with the interpretation of this png *outside* of Unity.   I want to edit this png in photoshop, but the information does not exist in any other program except for Unity.   The PNG that I have attached has baffled several colleagues and professors.  I am seeking an explanation so that this can be avoided in the creation of future assets.